# Can not assigned a bitmap object to QR code image returning from encoder

Tags: xamarin.ios

I installed  Xamarin studio and trying to use System.Drawing frame work but it is not working. The reason I want this framework is to be able to define a Bitmap object. This bitmap object is assigned to a qr code image. Can anyone help me on how i can assigned an image to bitmap since i can not use bitmap in xamarin studio framework.

What i wanna do is as follows:

```
       //create a qr code
QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();

  // Assign a bitmap image to the encoder since the encoder.encode returns bitmap image
    Bitmap img = encoder.Encode("http://www.monkeywow.com");

  // save the image in to images folder
   img.save("www.monkeywow.com/images/imp.jpg", ImageFormat.jpg);
```

The problem is I can not use Bitmap img since i can not import System.Drawing into Xamarin.
I tried that and did not work. Since the encoder returns bitmap, i do not know how to obtain the image so i can save it where ever i want.

Comment: "it is not working", can you please elaborate, possibly supplying some code and error messages as applicable?

Answer (score 0):

To display an image on screen, use UIImage.  For working with low level bitmaps, use the CoreImage framework.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/

http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/coreimage/

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.iOS includes a few `System.Drawing` types, e.g. `Rectangle[F]`, `Point[F]` and `Size[F]`, inside `monotouch.dll` to ease code sharing between (cross platform) projects.

However the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly itself is **not** part of the **mobile** profile that ships with Xamarin.iOS.

Like @Jason mentioned are several, native, ways you can do graphics on iOS (OpenGL would be another one).

Another option is to use the code from https://github.com/mono/sysdrawing-coregraphics which offers a partial System.Drawing API on top of CoreGraphics.